# How do I calculate the work done by snow when stopping a person from falling from a plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation

I have the following data:
Assume a man falling from a plane from a height of 370 m ($=h$) high (Straight down). The man falls into a pile of snow and creates a 1.1 m ($=d$) deep crater. The man has a mass of 88kg ($=m$) and his velocity right before hitting the snow was 45 m/s ($=v$). What is the amount of work done by the snow when stopping the man?

I've tried the following:

Since $W_{net}=\Delta K$
I can say that $W_G + W_S = K_1-K_0$
Where $W_G$ is the amount of work done by gravity, $W_S$ is the amount of work done by snow and $K_1$ and $K_0$ is respectively the amount of Kinetic energy after and before the person falls into the snow.
This gives me the equation:
$mg(h+d)+W_S=0- \frac{1}{2}mv^2$

This gives me the result of approx. $-409463$ $J$ for $W_S$.
Is this correct? My book tells me it should be $-9,0.10^4$ $J$ so either I'm wrong or my book is...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the height he jumped from because you have the speed at impact.  The air has done some work on him, reducing the kinetic energy at impact.  The work of the snow is precisely the energy removed.

Comment: Only because the work done by gravity over the 1.1m crater is pretty small so it's negligible. Gravity continues to add energy throughout the cratering process.

Comment: @tpg2114:  good point.